# Building generic order-by-statement

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I have a class with a bunch of properties:

```
class Foo {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public int Age {get; set; 
}
```

and a collection of instances of `Foo`.

Now I want to order those elements by a property given by the user. So the user selects a property from the type `Foo`. Now I want to order by elements based on this property.

One approach is a reflection-based one similar to this:

```
var p = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Age");
var ordered = fooList.OrderBy(x => (int) p.GetValue(x, null));
```

This works so far. However I also tried a second one and there I am stuck. It deals by performing an expression-tree as follows:

```
var f = GetOrderStatement<Foo>("Age");
var ordered = fooList.OrderBy(f)
```

With

```
Func<T, int> GetOrderStatement<T>(string attrName)
{
    var type = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), attrName);
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(type, attrName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(property).Compile();
}
```

My question is: As I should return a `Func<T, int>` where to get the `int`-part from or in other words where and how do I perform the actual comparison? I suppose I have to make a `CallExpression` to `IComparable.CompareTo` but I´m not sure how to do so. I think I need access to the both instances to compare.

EDIT: Complete code-example

```
static void Main()
{
    var fooList = new[] { new Foo("Hans", 10), new Foo("Georg", 12), new Foo("Birgit", 40) };
    var f = GetOrderStatement<Foo>("Age");
    var ordered = fooList.OrderBy(f);
}

private static Func<T, int> GetOrderStatement<T>(string attrName)
{
    var type = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), attrName);
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(type, attrName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(property).Compile();
}
```

Executing this code will throw an

> ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda
>   declaration

Comment: You don't perform the comparison - `OrderBy` does. You can pass in a custom comparer if you want to, but you wouldn't normally need to. What happens with the code you've shown so far?

Comment: It returns an `ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration` when calling `Compile()`.

Comment: Then that should be in the question :) If you can fix that issue, I suspect it will just work. I strongly advise you to rewrite this question in the form of a [mcve], including the exception. I suspect the fix is just to call `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(property, type)` but it would be easy to test that *if* we had a complete example.

Comment: That's still not a short but complete example. We should have a single block of text that we can copy, paste into a new file, compile and run. At the moment we'd have to copy Foo from one snippet, then add a bunch of `using` directives and another class (e.g. `Test` or `Program`) to contain the other methods. Additionally, the exception you've given is just the message, rather than the stack trace.

Comment: Oh, and as an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend using properties rather than public fields...

Comment: @JonSkeet Your previous comment pointed it out, I added the `type`-expression and it worked. Thank you. Btw.: As I allready mentioned those public fields are legacy-code, I know not beauty, however different problem :)

Comment: Yes, and I'm adding an answer to explain that - but please get in the habit of writing good questions with short but complete examples.

Comment: Are you sure you need a method like this? I'd avoid relying on accessing fields by name if possible. Maybe you could use a `public static readonly Func<Foo, int>` instead of `string` if you're using string literals, or you could build a `Dictionary<string, Func<Foo, int>>` or better, `Dictionary<FooColumnEnum, Func<Foo, int>>`?

Comment: @Luaan Well,  you´re right and I also try to reduce this kind of member-access. However the application should be able to order ANY given type (that´s of course not part of the question for simplicity). So I cannot simply create a map with all possible types and their members (or even if I´d use reflection to get the members).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to build a `Func<T, int>` but your call to `Expression.Lambda` doesn't specify the parameter expression, which means you can't expect it to create a delegate that *has* any parameters. Just specifying `type` as a second argument to `Expression.Lambda` works. Here's a complete example based on your question - note that I've changed the ages to prove that it's actually ordering, and I've updated your fields to read-only properties:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Foo 
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Age { get; }

    public Foo(string name, int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var fooList = new[]
        {
            new Foo("Hans", 12),
            new Foo("Georg", 10),
             new Foo("Birgit", 40)
        };
        var f = GetOrderStatement<Foo>("Age");
        var ordered = fooList.OrderBy(f);
        foreach (var item in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}: {item.Age}");
        }
    }

    private static Func<T, int> GetOrderStatement<T>(string attrName)
    {
        var type = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), attrName);
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(type, attrName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(property, type).Compile();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Georg: 10
Hans: 12
Birgit: 40
```